# Copy / replace (mirror) file only when file name different (mainly the version part of name) in source folder and target folder

Tags: batch-file

Just searched up and not get what I want. Here is this task:
I need to compare a file in source folder and target folder, whenever a new version of this file arrive in source folder, I need to check and compare it with target folder, if different, need to update the target folder with new version of this file, the new version of this file showing difference in name itself

```
set source=C:\Users\TSA
set target=C:\Users\test

if exist %source%\*.P3T (
        del %target%\*.P3T
        copy %source%\*.P3T %target%\   
    )
```

Tried to use comp command but end up having a pause to ask

```
comp %target%/*.P3T %source%/*.P3T
```

Compare more files (Y/N) ? I need to get rid of this without interruption...

Thanks all for your useful info.

Here is the code to do the job

```
Robocopy /MIR %source% %target%
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at the usage information for `RoboCopy`? You can do that by opening a Command Prompt window, and entering `RoboCopy /?`. _You may find that its `/Mon` and/or `/Mot` options are useful_.

Comment: Any new files that show up in the source folder will have the archive attribute set. Both `XCOPY` and `ROBOCOPY` have options for copying files when the archive attribute is set on a file.  It will then remove the archive attribute after it is done copying the file. Pretty sure I remember us discussing this on DosTips.com.

Comment: What about this: `echo N| comp ...`?

Comment: @goodywp, your question was specific that the idea was to monitor the directory; may I ask why you decided against the `/Mon` option I'd hinted at?

Comment: @Compo, since this is the beginning of my scripts to check if any thing new in the source folder then do copy/update to the destination folder, based upon the destination folder file, the rest of task kick off, in this way to make sure based upon the right /latest version of the file... I tested it and works fine to me. did not try /mon yet, this one looks like to monitor server, my situation is just a network folder, whenever it is needed, not a sort of schedule task....

Comment: @goodywp, I'll reiterate… Your 'so called' solution does not determine whether a new file has arrived in the source folder despite your question mentioning this! Please do not include requirements in your question that are not requirements. If you change your requirements after posting a question, it is appropriate to edit that question accordingly, for future readers.

Comment: @Compo, just modified the question itself now. Thanks for your help..